# How to create context that does not support being bound without read and draw surfaces

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, egl

In new extension of OpenGl ES 2.0 "surfaceless_context" its given the following:

If Context does not support being bound without read and draw
        surfaces, and both  and  are EGL_NO_SURFACE, an
        EGL_BAD_MATCH error is generated.

I am unable to create such a context. I tried making the context shared but no luck.

Link: http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context.txt

Answer (score 1):

When creating an EGL context, it's impossible to request that the context support the "surfaceless_context" extension. The driver chooses to make the context surfaceless or not; you don't get that choice.

To detect if it's legal to call `eglMakeCurrent(dpy, EGL_NO_SURFACE, ctx)` with a given context, you must check that the EGL extension string contains `EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context` and the context's extension string contains `GL_OES_surfaceless_context`. Both extensions must be present.

Answer (score 0):

This extension is so new (1 year) it's unlikely to be supported by many of the OpenGL ES 2.0 drivers in use for the Android platform.  I recommend you avoid using this unless you can find a platform where it is supported.